# Spring MVC: How to call @Service class from another project

Tags: java, spring, maven, service, annotations

I'm having a problem right now, Is it possible to use anotated @Service class from another Maven Spring MVC project? I've already done this step: Build Path -> Configure Path -> Add Project

Now, I'm trying to use some annotated service method from added project.

the following code is my controller class and i want to use CustomerService class method from another project which I already added in configure path.

### CustomerController.java

```
//this class is from another project
private CustomerService customerService;

public ModelAndView searchCustomer(@RequestParam String lastname) {
    CustomerService customerService = this.customerService.findByLastName(lastname);

}
```

Or is there any alternate way to use annotated Service class from another project?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just add the project as a maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If I do the job, I may:
1. Copy the source java file into my new project
2. Export the other project into a jar, and then import into my new project.

Answer (score 0):

Consider breaking your application into web, service and DAL layer into different maven modules like below:-

- Main Project (bundled as pom)
- Web module (bundled as war with Service dependency)
- Service (bundled as jar with DAL dependency)
- DAL (bundled as jar)

Above structure gives you enough flexibility to plug out Services (as jar) and include it in any other application